# Google Apps Script - Spreadsheet - Create onEdit Dropdown list in a cell based on values not coming from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

I have seen examples on how to create a dropdown list based on values coming from Range values from other spreadsheets, dropdown list depending on a cell value. In all examples i have seen, values were coming from range values from other spreadsheets.

What i want to achieve is :

- in a spreadsheet with column headers, i have no line.
- when i edit the 1st cell, it shows a dropdown list with values. Only when i edit the cell. If possible i would like not to pre-populate a the cell of the st column for a fixed number of rows, cause i am thinking this may consumes time, and i do not know how many cells there will be there in the file in one month.
- values from the dropdown list are retrieved from another Google Workspace Service.

What i experienced at the moment :

- I am able to retrieve the values i want to display in my dropdown list
- If i am right, to construct a dropdown list, there is to use the SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation() method to build the dropdown list
- My values are stored in a 2 dimensional array, as it seems this would be the way to pass the values to a range of cells that is passed into parameter of the previous method, with the Build method at the end
- i was able to set the values for a range of cells (ex: A1:A10) and display a dropdown list icon on each cell, but the values displayed when editing the cells are like val1;val2;val3...

My questions :

- How do i create a dynamic dropdown list on the cell of the 1st column, dynamically, when i edit the cell ? If the cell of the 1st colum has to be prefilled, then at least why not

I do not know if iwa clear enough. This is the idea of the script :

```
var v_spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var v_sheet = v_spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
// I imagine i could specify A1:A1 to specify only the cell that is being edited ?
var range = v_sheet.getRange("A2:A5");
// my array below is 2 dimensions : v_array[0][0] = 'val1', v_array[0][1] = 'val2', etc
range.setValues(v_array_taskLists);
var dd_values = range.getValues();
var validationRule   = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(dd_values).build();
range.setDataValidation(validationRule);
```

As you can see i am passing by a range data, which may not be the correct way

Any help greatly appreciated
Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you said you are able to retrieve the correct data you want to display in the dropdown. You can use this function to populate it. Where `range` is a range of cells and `list` is the list of values you want displayed in the dropdown.

```
function setRangeDataValidation(range, list) {
  var rangelValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(list)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .build();
  range.setDataValidation(rangelValidation);
}
```

You can change the values available in the dropdown dynamically using the `onChange` trigger (that's the approach I used in a similar application). Let's say you want to have the data validation change in column `A` when some change is made in another column, say `B` in the same row.

```js
function onChange(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var ws = ss.getActiveSheet()

    if (e.changeType === 'EDIT') {
      var activeRange = ws.getActiveRange();
      var editCol = activeRange.getColumn();
      
      if (editCol === 1) {
        // in case more rows are changed at the same time (copy and paste)
        var numRows = activeRange.getNumRows();
        var startRow = activeRange.getRow();

        var yourList = //the list to be updated in the dropdown

        //You can loop through the list of values that were edited in column A in case you want a different dropdown in column B for each value passed in column A.
        for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
          // Here if you want different lists in the dropdown for different cells in columns A you can do the following
          //var cellColA = activeRange.getCell(startRow + row, 1).getValue();
          // yourList = updatedList;

          // Then et range of cell in column B
          var cellColB = ws.getRange(startRow + row, 2);
          setRangeDataValidation(cellColB, youList)
        }
      }
    }
```

Keep in mind though that the `onChange` trigger is an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange) trigger that you can install in this way:

```js
function createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onChange')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

#### Notes:

- If you just need to track changes to the spreadsheet content, and not its structure, it's arguably more appropriate to use an installable [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange) trigger instead of an [onChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onchange) one.
- Installing this via an `onOpen` trigger is not a good idea, since this will install a new trigger every time the spreadsheet is opened, and you will end up with many duplicate triggers.

Comment: Hi @everspader, 1st of all, many many thx for taking time to answer to me so quickly and trying to help me.

I will try to explain step by step what I am facing :
- Just when reloading the spreadsheet in which the script is bounded to, i get a "classic" GoogleJsonResponseException exception failing because "missing required authentication credential", and expecting valid authentication credential (oAuth, cookie, ..). I tried to create a new GCP Project, create oAuth, and relink my script to the project without success. So i renamed the onChange function and added a trigger to it

Comment: - The new function triggered when opening the sheet launches my custom fct getting the values to be retrieved from another G.Service (tasks...). At the end of the function i am calling your fct setRangeDataValidation to try to set the values in the cell A2:A2. Dropdown icon is correctly displayed in the cell but it gives me choice "val1,val2,val3" as a text value. When i select the value, i get a Data validation error msg.. If i edit the data validation properties of the cells and click save on popup then the value is correctly displayed in the DDlist : How do i correct this ?

Comment: i would like to understand 1st, how to correctly display the value in the DDList. Should i already give a specific format to my cells, do a sort of refresh, or anything else ?

Many thx for your answer and sorry for these replies, these may be easy things to do but i am not experienced enough anymore in Google Apps Script

Comment: here is a link to my Spreadsheet if you want to see the bad things i tried to do : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jmfHiI8lIHIh-X-47i2dAn0SIgsB7Mt-yOb046uoAjU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's hard to see anything in the sheet without editing access. It seems to me that the list  you are getting from wherever to populate the dropdown is not correct, that's why you see "val1, val2, val3". Unless it's a list with one item like `["val1,val2,val3"]`. So if you wanted to have these 3 values displayed, you probably need to do a split in the string into a list first. You can play around with the properties of the data validation in the `setRangeDataValidation` to see if you can find what matches your needs

Comment: I don't think running `createSpreadsheetChangeTrigger` in an `onOpen` is a good idea, since that would create a new trigger every time the spreadsheet is opened. Also what's the reason for using an `onChange` and not an `onEdit`?

Comment: @AlexisTruong `it gives me choice "val1,val2,val3" as a text value` that means you are providing a string instead of an array. You should [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string. If you have problems with this, please provide more details about how this data is being imported.

Comment: Hi everspader, Hi @lamblichus,
Thanks for your replies, really.

Spreadsheet File access is corrected (link above, sorry)

You will see that my array is a 2-dim array : 
v_array_taskLists[0][0] = "val1" 
v_array_taskLists[0][1] = "val2"
etc.

Why ? I followed the idea that i would use an middle step with a range.setValues(values) method which requires a 2-dim array then retrieve the range value and pass it in the requiredValueInList() method. Probably dumb and useless.

Many thanks for your help again :)

Comment: @AlexisTruong I think it's because you have a list of lists with only one element `[[1, 2, 3, 4]]` instead of a list of lists with several elements `[[1],[2],[3]]`. I left some comments in the sheet. Also changed the opening function to `onOpen()` so the triggers are run when opening the sheet.

Comment: The way you wrote it, a new trigger will be installed when the spreadsheet is opened. This way you will probably end up with many `onChange` triggers installed. Also, since the user wants to run this when a cell is edited, I don't see any reason to use an `onChange` trigger instead of an installed [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onEdit()) trigger. Could you clarify about these points?

Comment: @everspader Many thanks for your feedback. I understood the issue with my array now. I am so gratefull for your help and the time you took to help me..

Comment: @lamblichus you are right, this installs a new trigger each time. I will see how to deal with this. At least thanks to everspader i know how to correctly store my values. Now i have to see if i can make appear the dropdown list icon when i edit the cell (not sure this is possible with onChange but maybe with onEdit ?)

Comment: I just remembered why I used `onChange` instead of `onEdit`. It's because the change method gives you the type of change like `edit`, `insert row` and so on. So yes you can use only the onEdit trigger. I did some fixes on you sheet @AlexisTruong and left some comments. I hope it helps.

Comment: @everspader many thanks again, i cannot believe you did all this. I have read your comments and i totally understand the mechanism.
So many steps are now ok thanks to you.

What i understand is that i will not able to :
- enter editmode in a cell and display the dropdown list selector in it without making any change (in another cell like with ur depedent DD. OnEdit is not triggered when entering editMode)

So i may think in :
- at 1st launch, displaying 1st row with the DD in A2:A2
- adding a button in the row above like "Add line" which will add a new empty line with the DD

Comment: @everspader i will go ahead with your code and recommendations and will let you know.
In all cases, i am very gratefull for the time you spent to help me. This has no price. I keep you informed ;)

Comment: @AlexisTruong you're welcome. Yes, you can do that. You can enter the onEdit in a cell, ay "A2" and add the dropdown to itself. You just need to change the column of the "editCol" and be aware that the function `setRangeDataValidation` needs to have `setAllowInvalid(false)` so you can add a value that is not in the list. And remove the `requireValueInList(list)` so you don't get a red warning. If that helped you can you please accept my first answer :)

Comment: Many thanks @everspader this really helped me a lot !
Thanks also lamblichus :)